# Docker compose just new containers

Tags: docker

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which brings up several services (redis, db, mongo, app). I made a script to bring up Docker environment up, but forcing you to forward environment variable which will act as a subdomain for the app (which is a PHP web app).

So for the app container I have:

```
app:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
  image: xxx:xxx
  container_name:my-app-${ENV}
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    ...
```

Now what I would like is to be able to fire up several apps which all depend on already brought up containers (for example `app1.com` and `app2.com` using the same DB).

So I was trying to bring it up by using:

```
ENV=$1 VIRTUAL_HOST=$1.com docker-compose up -d --build app
```

(I am using nginx container to enable virtual hosts, and `$1` comes from bash script). But what this does is just rebuilds already existing app container and adds a new name.

Can I run `docker-compose` while building completely new app container, leaving others intact if they already exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `docker-compose up -d [NEW APPNAME]` to build/run a specific app in the compose file

try...

```
docker-compose build [appName]
docker-compose up --no-deps -d [appName]
```

The first command builds the new container with `[appName]`

The 2nd command stops, destroys, and recreates just the `[appName]` container.

The  `--no-deps` flag prevents Compose from recreating any services which [appName] depends on

your apps have to have different names since compose is going to build, stop, create all containers with that name.

so your compose file should be similar to:

```
app: 
  build: 
  context: . 
  dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile 
  image: xxx:xxx 
  container_name:my-app-${ENV} 
  restart: always 
  depends_on: ...

app2: 
  build: 
  context: . 
  dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile 
  image: xxx:xxx 
  container_name:my-app2-${ENV} 
  restart: always 
  depends_on: ...

app3: 
  build: 
  context: . 
  dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile 
  image: xxx:xxx 
  container_name:my-app3-${ENV} 
  restart: always 
  depends_on: ...
```

the above is using the same Dockerfile for app containers.

to use different dockerfiles for each app just change path of `dockerfile`

Comment: This doesn't quite do it, it just overwrites the already existing container. Don't know if I was clear in the question, but I would like to have `my-app-1` and `my-app-2` as side by side running containers. I keep overwriting the container with `docker-compose`, it never creates another one running along the first one created.